# How to limit the telescope entries in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, telescope

We are using telescope to monitor our laravel application. but telescope is using big amount of database. Yes we can delete records . But is there any way that we only allow telescope to insert record related to queues and schedule commands not all data like requests , database queries and many other things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in `app\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider.php`

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope#filtering):

> You may filter the data that is recorded by Telescope via the `filter`
> callback that is registered in your `TelescopeServiceProvider`. By
> default, this callback records all data in the `local` environment and
> exceptions, failed jobs, scheduled tasks, and data with monitored tags
> in all other environments:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->hideSensitiveRequestDetails();

    Telescope::filter(function (IncomingEntry $entry) {
        if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
            return true;
        }

        return $entry->isReportableException() ||
            $entry->isFailedJob() ||
            $entry->isScheduledTask() ||
            $entry->hasMonitoredTag();
    });
}
```

As you can see it will only report the following when `APP_ENV` is not set to `local`:

```
isReportableException()
isFailedJob()
isScheduledTask()
hasMonitoredTag()
```

So if you set your `APP_ENV` to `production` it should not record every request.